# Duplicate RazorLanguageVersionAttribute building container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, build, attributes, duplicates

I am trying to build a docker container comprising a ASP.NET core web site. When trying to build the container, I am getting errors about duplicate Razor*Attributes. I have suppressed generation of AssemblyInfo in the project file. I have found solutions online which call for removal of *\bin \obj* and the folders generated by VS, but this is Docker. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The folders */obj* and */bin* should be excluded from image build process by adding file [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file):

**.dockerignore**

```sh
# resolve this issue
**/bin
**/obj
# recommended options
.dockerignore
.env
.git
.gitignore
.vs
.vscode
docker-compose.yml
docker-compose.*.yml
_ReSharper.Caches
**/bower_components
**/node_modules
**/*.*proj.user
**/.cache
**/charts
**/Dockerfile
**/Dockerfile.develop
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
**/azds.yaml
**/.vs
```

It prevents the occurring errors like these too:

```
error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute
error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute' attribute
error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute' attribute
error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute' attribute
error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute' attribute
error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute' attribute
error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute
```